# Send byte array to server

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have an image object that I need to save on the server. I convert it into an array of bytes, and then serialize it into JSON with my optional data. But the server can not successfully convert it and it returns an error message to me:

```
{
"Message": "Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'",
"StackTrace": " at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.AssignToPropertyOrField(Object propertyValue, Object o, String memberName, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertDictionaryToObject(IDictionary`2 dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject) at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams) at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams) at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)",
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException"
}
```

**My Json Data which i send:**

```
{
  "articleData": {
    "ArticleNumber": "002",
    "ArticlePhoto": "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"
  },
  "sessionId": "d98b2c41-373a-40af-ac3b-874198e22a08"
}
```

**My Request provider:**

```
public class JsonProvider : IJsonProvider
    {
        private const string JsonContentType = "application/json";


        public async Task<TResult> MakeApiCall<TResult,TData>(string url, HttpMethod method, TData data)
            where TResult : class
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url))
                {
                    if (method != HttpMethod.Get)
                    {
                        var json = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data))
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);
                        request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, JsonContentType);
                    }

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);

                    var stringSerialized = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);


                    return await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(serialize))
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Request Objects:**

```
public class SessionRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("sessionId")] public string SessionId { get; set; }
    }

public class UploadArticlePhotoRequest : SessionRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("articleData")] public PhotoRequest ArticleData { get; set; }
    }

public class PhotoRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("ArticleNumber")] public string ArticleNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ArticlePhoto")] public byte[] ArticlePhoto { get; set; }
    }
```

Can the problem in the format of conversion or encoding? Is it a client application or server problem?

Comment: Issue should be with your TData which is not the same type you are sending your data for

Answer (score 0):

> Can the problem in the format of conversion or encoding? Is

Read the error message. It is clear. "Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'".

> Is it a client application or server problem?

Well, obviously - gibven it is a .NET level error - the error happens on the server. Now, this may be bad data sent, but generally that would be seen as a server level error.

You basically made up a TData and it is not compatible with the data sent.

Happens - lack of reading details. That ALSO leads to horrific code like this:

> return await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialize))
>                          .ConfigureAwait(false);

Just skip the Task.run and deserialize sync. See, there is no async method for that - with good reason - and you do not gain aynthign with Task.RUn, all you do is make sure 2 threads wait, not one. Antipattern from a lack of reading details and thinking things through. There is no way JsonConvert should be async to start (it is CPU bound, not IO bound) and you force the use of a separate task for it, while the original one waits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, also about Json Serialization / Deserialization